# How can i display just one copy of an item from mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am working on a search engine for a library where users can look up books... the search works well but some books have duplicated copies so that its available to more persons. I want just one copy to display during search so i tried using "DISTINCT" in my query but it turns out to be these books have distinct book_id, and I cant exclude book_id because its being used to identify individual books to show on the details page. PLease what can I do to show just one copy of a book?

```
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT call_no,book_id,main_title,author1,itm_type,publdate,image,subj1 FROM records WHERE $dropdown LIKE '%$search%'" or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: Show your table structure and sample data on sqlfiddle please

Comment: If you don't do a `SELECT *` the keyword `DISTINCT` should work somehow.

Comment: just included my query

Answer (score 0):

Try using GROUP BY for column which is same for all book instancies. Probably main_title?

```
$query = "SELECT call_no,book_id,main_title,author1,itm_type,publdate,image,subj1 FROM records WHERE $dropdown LIKE '%$search%' GROUP BY main_title" or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: @EjirogheneDanielOdiete: Then if this solution worked for you don't forget to upvote/select as solution.

Answer (score 0):

Going by your query, looks like you need to refactor your table. Something like this:

```
Book_Table
 - id
 - title 
 - author

Catelog_Table
  - id 
  - book_id
```

Each book's meta data can go into Boot_table

Your individual books can go into Catelog_table.